# BNL 2 R/FI VISA

Tags: schengen-visas

I have a Schengen tourist multiple visa with remarks BNL2 R/FI. That visa was issued to me thru The Netherlands embassy in Pakistan by the Finish authority.

I used to travel frequent Netherlands and it is the 2nd time that embassy has granted me with 1 year multiple entry visa.

May I know what on visa sticker BNL2 R/FI represents.

Answer (score 3):

> May I know what on visa sticker BNL2 R/FI represents.

Based on the information found in Annex 22 of the visa handook:

> BENELUX
>
> Common data which may be entered when an A, B, C or D+C visa is issued:
>
> - BNL2
>
>   - visa issued ex officio.
>
> ...
> for the Netherlands when an A, B, C, D+C and D or multiple entry visa is issued: **the alien's number**;

This will be a visa issued by a responsible consulate official (BNL1: visa issued following authorisation by the central authorities ; BNL3: issued at border point ;  BNL4: visa issued in the framework of representation following consultation of the represented State).

The **R/FI**, although it doesn't look like a number to me, according to the documentation should be 'the alien's number'.

---

> In fact I forgot to mention you that I have applied a Finish visa Thru The Netherlands embassy who is representing Finish embassy in Pakistan.

It would seem the *R/FI* is based on the, now obsolete, Annex VII syntax using the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) instead of the [ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) which should now be used in the uniform format for visas.

> [2016-04-12: Visa Code - Annex VII (removed 2019-06-20)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20160412#tocId82)
> **ANNEX VII**
> **FILLING IN THE VISA STICKER**
> ...
> 9. (a) Mandatory entries to be added in the ‘COMMENTS’ section
>
> - in the case of a visa issued on behalf of another Member State pursuant to Article 8, the following mention is added: ‘**R/[Code of represented Member State]**’,
>
> ...

The **Code of represented Member State** is the ISO alpha 2 country code used in the point 1.1 of ANNEX VII:

> (b) Schengen State or Schengen States to whose territory the validity of the visa is limited (in this case the following abbreviations are used):
> ...
> **FI** FINLAND.
> ...

**Note**:
Annex VII was removed from the Visa Code on the 20 June 2019:

> [EUR-Lex - 32019R1155 - EN - EUR-Lex](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32019R1155)
> (42) Annexes **VII**, VIII and IX are deleted;

---

**Sources**:

- [Annex 22 (July.2021) 1 National entries in the "comments" section of the visa sticker - Nyidanmark.dk](https://nyidanmark.dk/-/media/Files/US/Lovstof/Visumkodeks/Visumhaandbogen/annex_22.pdf)
- [Ex officio member - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_officio_member)
- [2003-05-01: Common Consular Instructions (CCI)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02002X1216%2802%29-20030501)
- [2020-02-02: Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202)

  - [2016-04-12: Visa Code - Annex VII (removed 2019-06-20)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20160412#tocId82)
- [amending Council Regulation (EC) No 1683/95 laying down a uniform format for visas](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32017R1370)

Comment: My first thought was that the visa was issued in representation of Finland, but that would usually be BNL4 R/FIN (though BNL2 might be possible if they can issue it without consultation) and OP's main destination seems to be NL.

Comment: @xngtng That was might first thought too, that is why I added the full BNL4 text.

Comment: In fact I forgot to mention you that I have applied a Finish visa Thru The Netherlands embassy who is representing Finish embassy in Pakstan. 

In that case, would my first point of entry be Finland or I can touch directly Netherlands

Comment: @RazaAfzal Please add that information to your question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson sure plz

Comment: Thank you @xngtng